# fail to compiling elephant-bird with mvn

Tags: maven, hadoop

I just can't solve my issue, even it would probably be obvious to you. So can anyone help me ?

The problem occured when I tried to build elephant bird based on it's source code.
I executed `mvn package`

And it returned:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] One or more required plugin parameters are invalid/missing for 'protobuf:run'
```

Inside the definition for plugin 'protobuf-maven-plugin' specify the following:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <inputDirectories>VALUE</inputDirectories>
</configuration>
```

-OR-

on the command line, specify: '-DinputDirectories=VALUE'

I tried to install protobuf, but it still don't work.
So, does it means I have specify the param?  And how to specify the param?

Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide us your full pom. It seems that you forgot some parameters, and even I don't know Hadopp way of building, it would be easier for us.

Comment: the pom is provided by the author of elephant-bird, not written by myself.Luckily, I successfully solve this problem today, just change maven2 to maven 3, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `protobuf 2.3` - NOT `2.4`! (read [here](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird)!)

Also, make sure you use `maven3`, I had some problems with `maven2`.